# How to convert the Javascript Regex in Java RegEx without break the functionality

Tags: javascript, java

I have RegEx which is used in java script.I want to convert the same RegEx in to Java RegEx.

```
var finalValue=curVal.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\t,./;':<>?`\-~!@#$%^&()_+="[\]{\}|\*]/g, " ");
```

I want to apply the above regex in java in following pattern without break functionality

```
String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement);
```

Example :

```
String str="Customer AA: 2 TSRAs for closing the accounts. No suspicion is noted although the client is moving back to Iran.. HKD1531504.84.";
String finalStr=str.replaceAll("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\t,./;':<>?`\-~!@#$%^&()_+="[\]{\}|\*]/g", " ");
```

Comment: Could you add some description what exactly do you want to select with this regex?

Comment: What attempt have you made to do this in Java?

Comment: I need to replace the all the characters which i mentioned in the regex.

Comment: @nazar_art I have mentioned in Java script Regex. I am not able to convert same regex in java.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Please show how you've attempted to do this in Java. For what reason are you unable to simply paste in that exact regex to the `String.replaceAll` method you show?

Comment: @khelwood Just convert of same reg ex from JS to Java. I am not able to convert.Can you convert the regex

Comment: @Klaycon I am not able to convert. Thats why i am requested to convert From Js Regex to Java regex. i think you got my point.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Please show how you tried to write the Java code.

Comment: @Klaycon i have updated the question.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri you showed input string and regex -> However, what should be final result after replacing?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question. hope you get my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that while JavaScript has a [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for regular expressions (this is the `/.../g` syntax), Java does not. In Java, you do not pass a RegEx using slashes. As you've quoted in your answer, the function signature for `String.replaceAll()` accepts a *String* as the first argument, which you are not providing.

It should work if you simply replace the slashes and global flag (replaceAll already attempts effectively a global match) with quotes to make it a String literal. Like this:

```
String str="Customer AA: 2 TSRAs for closing the accounts. No suspicion is noted although the client is moving back to Iran.. HKD1531504.84.";
String finalStr=str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\t,./;':<>?`\\-~!@#$%^&()_+=\"[\\]{\\}|\\*]", " ");
```

Notice that there is a double quotation mark in the regex itself, so I escaped it with `\"`. There are also backslashes, which must be escaped with `\\`.

Comment: I am getting error in Java -- Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: Some what helped but i am not able to get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Apologies, please see the edited answer. Forgot to escape the backslashes too.

Comment: [\\]{\\}|\\*]"  this part will not be included in the regex part as regex ends with " ( double quotation). hope you understand the basic problem

Comment: Only Regex is consider the ( "[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\t,./;':<>?`\\-~!@#$%^&()_+=\" ) part only

Comment: @LovaChittumuri it does not end with the double quotation if you escape it with `\"`. if you've added an additional backslash to `\n`, `\t`, or `\"`, you should remove it. an escaped double quote does not end a string